# how to get the div id of a specific level of DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

consider my html page be like this

```
<html>
 <body>
   <div id = "mainDiv">
     <div id = "levelOne1">
        <div id="levelTwo1">
          <div id = "levelThree1">
              third level html content over here
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="levelTwo2">
               second level html content over here
        </div>
     </div>
      <div id = "levelOne2">
             second level html content over here in levelOne2      
     </div>
      <div id = "levelOne3">
                <div id="innerdiv">
             second level html content over here in levelOne3   
                 </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and this function in js returns the id of the respective parent from where you have selected the text from

```
function getSelectionParentElement() {
  var parent = null,
  selection;
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount) {
      parent = selection.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
      if (parent.nodeType !== 1) {
          parent = parent.parentNode;
      }
    }
  } else if ((selection = document.selection) && selection.type !== "Control") {
    parent = selection.createRange().parentElement();
  }
  return parent;
}
```

and if i call this code after selecting some text from this
 `third level html content over here` from html page  and on any click function i wrote the code as

```
var divElement = getSelectionParentElement();

var divID = divElement.getattribute('id');
```

where `divID` is obtained as `levelThree1`.

**but what i want is the id of corresponding level two div** that is `levelOne1`

let me be clear ***i always want the id the of the respective second level div***

so if i select something from this text

`second level html content over here`

**i still want id as `levelOne1`**

and if i select sonething from this text

`second level html content over here in levelOne2`

**the div id should be `levelOne2`**

and if is select this text

`second level html content over here in levelOne3`
**the div id should be `levelOne3`**

is there any way of accomplishing it?

can we generalize it? like second level, third level etc?

Comment: So you just want to have a function that returns closest parent of selected element that has its id starting with "level"?

Comment: @lucifer63 no you didnt understand, i want the respective second level div id, the name of the id can be anything, i just gave the id name starting with level so that we can understand which level is it

Comment: will main div always be `mainDiv`?  If so you could recurse up the tree and stop when the `parentNode.id` is mainDiv

Comment: @Pete yes :) i give it dynamically and load html content to the second level div dynamically, i aslo give the name of the second level div dynamically as page loads

Comment: Not related to your question but you could make your code better readable by changing `parent.nodeType !== 1` to `parent.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE`

Comment: @Mukund, ehm, sounds bizarre, i think you're trying to achieve something that you actually can avoid; i mean it can be done in a much easier way. But ok. You can create a function like `getRelativeAncestor` that will accept `container` and `level` as arguments. Itay's function is a good example, but you don't have to hardcode the #mainDiv container, it should get acquired dinamically. Then you modify this function to accept your selected element and use it's parents to filter ancestors.

Comment: @lucifer63 i am sorry i am not so good in js, but while creating the page i added a div as mainDiv, then started loading html pages inside the mainDiv in seperate divs. so naturally i want to get the second level parent div. Any easier way is ok. but i have my limitations please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a particular class to the second level elements. For example, add class 'second-level-element' to all the second level elements. In your case you can add class 'second-level-element' to divs with Ids levelOne1, levelOne2, levelThree.

Then do this to check that the selected element is descendent of which second level element:

considering 'elem' is selected element,

```
function getSecondLevelElement(elem) {
    while (elem = elem.parentNode) { 
        if (elem.className == "second-level-element") {
            return id = elem.id;
        }
    }
}
```

And then call this function by passing the element whose text is selected as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just use generic function:

```js
function getIdByLevel(level){
  var element = $("#mainDiv");  // <- set the container in which you're searching
  for (var i = 0; i < level; i++){
    element = $(element).find("div")[0]; // <- the first div in each level is being taken
  }
  $("#res").html("id is: " + element.id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="levelOne1">
    <div id="levelTwo1">
      <div id="levelThree1">
        third level html content over here
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="levelTwo2">
      second level html content over here
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="levelOne2">
    second level html content over here in levelOne2
  </div>
  <div id="levelOne3">
    <div id="innerdiv">
      second level html content over here in levelOne3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<button onClick="getIdByLevel(1);">Get Level 1 Id</button>
<button onClick="getIdByLevel(2);">Get Level 2 Id</button>
<button onClick="getIdByLevel(3);">Get Level 3 Id</button>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Comment: but i want to get the id of the selected text, it can be from any where in the page, i am sorry if i dint understood your answer correctly. The correct id of the selected text from the respective id's  levelOne1,  levelOne2 or  levelOne3

Comment: I probably didn't understand what you need. Please edit your question and explain better

Answer (score 1):

If i understood well you can use child nodes.

```
var divElement = getSelectionParentElement();
var secondDiv = divElement.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
var divID = secondDiv.getattribute('id');
```

I separated the secondDiv in a new variable to be clear. But you can write all in one line.
Also you can use '.children[1]' instead of '.getElementsByTagName('div')[1]', the difference is that children[1] will get the second child in the divElement no matter if it is a div or p or another kind of element.

Another choice may be use ":nth-child(n)" pseudoclass with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mukesh Patil, i accomplished the same

```
function getSecondLevelElement(elem) {
                var immediateId = new Array();
                var i =0;
                    while (elem = elem.parentNode) { 
                        if(elem.getAttribute('id')==="mainDiv")
                        {
                      console.log(elem.getAttribute('id')+"  <> "+i); 

                      break;
                        }
                        immediateId[i] = elem.getAttribute('id');
                      i=i+1;
                    }
                    return immediateId[i-1];
                }
```